# Disable drag and drop/ Show row weights

Tags: 7

The drag and drop screws up my theme when viewing it on a mobile device. Since this feature isn't necessary for my site can i completely remove these options to my users? I want to remove *all* drag and drop functionality.

Im using corolla Corolla 7.x-3.0-rc1.

This can be duplicated by viewing my site and dragging the window to be the smallest width. The drag and drop table does not adjust its width.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to alter [`settings.tableDrag`](http://drupal.org/node/1488466) to remove that drag and drop functionality, but I think what you're actually running into is a css rule that sets a width for the table.

Comment: This isn't part of a module but rather a node of a content-type. is this still the recommended approach?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a drag-and-drop table inside your nodes? If you edit your question to include more information about the following, I can help better. What does "screws up my theme" mean? Which theme is it? What is it that you want to remove? (The javascript file, the css class, etc?) Have you tried taking those out to see how it reacts?

Comment: Im using corolla Corolla 7.x-3.0-rc1
I want to remove all drag and drop functionality.
Currently the node has a field with the "unlimited values" selected.  This allows the user to then add another field and drupal automatically includes the show row weights, or drag and drop feature. I want to completely get rid of the ability to drag and drop from the content type.  
It screws up my theme in that it has a fixed width when viewing on a mobile device. This can be duplicated by viewing my site and dragging the window to be the smallest width. The drag and drop table does not adjust its width.

Comment: The CSS can be overridden to simply include media queries for your mobile devices. No need to remove the functionality completely. So Beth was correct to begin with. +1

Comment: I would rather remove the functionality so my users dont have the the option to click "show row weights" and end up seeing a bunch of numbers